# Can't open multiple windows in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

so I've made several GUIs using the PyQt designer and I aim for each of them to link with eachother and for them to be able to open eachother. I have gotten the start up page to open up the home page, however when I click the respective buttons on the home page to open the other pages, it crashes my program. Any help would in fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

My code is below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from StartupPage import Ui_StartupWindow
from HomePage import Ui_HomeWindow
from FoodPage import Ui_FoodWindow
from ExercisePage import Ui_ExerciseWindow
from ProfilePage import Ui_ProfileWindow

class Startup(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_StartupWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Startup, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.NewEntryButton.clicked.connect(self.NewButtonHandle)
        self.ContinueButton.clicked.connect(self.ContinueButtonHandle)
        self.HomeP=Home()

    def NewButtonHandle(self):
        self.HomeP.show()

    def ContinueButtonHandle(self):
        self.HomeP.show()

class Home(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_HomeWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.FoodP=Food()
        self.ExerciseP=Exercise()
        self.ProfileP=Profile()
        self.exerciseButton.clicked.connect(self.ExerciseButtonHandle)
        self.foodButton.clicked.connect(self.FoodButtonHandle)
        self.profileButton.clicked.connect(self.ProfileButtonHandle)

    def ExerciseButtonHandle():
        self.ExerciseP.show()

    def FoodButtonHandle():
        self.FoodP.show()

    def ProfileButtonHandle():
        self.ProfileP.show()

class Food(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_FoodWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class Exercise(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ExerciseWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class Profile(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ProfileWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Startup()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

try to move import sys to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys  """<--------------------------here"""
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Startup()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

try to check that other you import modules such as this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import Homepage                    #import the whole thing
```

then:

```
class Home(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Homepage.Ui_HomeWindow):
      #import the UI there
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be useful to know what error message is displayed when the program crashes.

Having said that, I was fiddling with something similar recently and the below seems to work fine. Note it is mostly the same as what you were doing.

Also, I had wanted to prevent interaction with the main (home) window when any of it's child windows (window1, window2, window3) were open, to force the user to focus on one task at a time rather than opening multiple windows - hence the setEnabled() calls. The

```
self.Window1.setEnabled(True)
```

line is required in home.toWindow1() because the Window1 is a member of home, and as such gets disabled along with all other members of home as a result of the first setEnabled call.

Also, while I did put my

```
import sys
```

in the main method as suggested by Volodymyr, that's just for the sake of neatness. As references to sys will resolve just as well (scoping rules, LEGB) if the import is the first line of code or the first line in the main method, I don't see how having it in either location could cause any issues (unless it was imported at the start of the file and then later the variable sys was assigned a different value).

I also don't see that altering the import, as suggested by Bahnzo, from

```
from HomePage import Ui_HomeWindow
```

to

```
import HomePage
```

and then later referring to Ui_HomeWindow as HomePage.Ui_HomeWindow would make any difference, for the same reason - the only case it would is if Ui_homePage had some value explicitly assigned to it after the import occurred and before it was used in the class definition - and you can see that doesn't happen in the OP's code.

```
#!/bin/python3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from startwindow import Ui_startWindow
from homewindow import Ui_homeWindow
from window1 import Ui_Window1
from window2 import Ui_Window2
from window3 import Ui_Window3


class start(QMainWindow, Ui_startWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(start, self).__init__(None)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.homeButton.clicked.connect(self.toHome)
        self.home = home()

    def toHome(self):
        self.home.show()
        self.hide()

class home(QMainWindow, Ui_homeWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(home, self).__init__(None)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.window1Button.clicked.connect(self.toWindow1)
        self.window2Button.clicked.connect(self.toWindow2)
        self.window3Button.clicked.connect(self.toWindow3)
        self.Window1 = window1(self)
        self.Window2 = window2(self)
        self.Window3 = window3(self)

    def toWindow1(self):
        self.Window1.show()
        self.setEnabled(False)
        self.Window1.setEnabled(True)

    def toWindow2(self):
        self.Window2.show()
        self.setEnabled(False)
        self.Window2.setEnabled(True)

    def toWindow3(self):
        self.Window3.show()
        self.setEnabled(False)
        self.Window3.setEnabled(True)

    def reEnable(self):
        self.setEnabled(True)

class window1(QMainWindow, Ui_Window1):
    def __init__(self, home):
        super(window1, self).__init__(home)
        self.home = home
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.homeButton.clicked.connect(self.toHome)

    def toHome(self):
        self.home.setEnabled(True)
        self.hide()


class window2(QMainWindow, Ui_Window2):
    def __init__(self, home):
        super(window2, self).__init__(home)
        self.home = home
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.homeButton.clicked.connect(self.toHome)

    def toHome(self):
        self.home.setEnabled(True)
        self.hide()

class window3(QMainWindow, Ui_Window3):
    def __init__(self, home):
        super(window3, self).__init__(home)
        self.home = home
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.homeButton.clicked.connect(self.toHome)

    def toHome(self):
        self.home.setEnabled(True)
        self.hide()
```